# Quartz 2 + Hibernate 4 multitenant erratic behaviour

Tags: spring, hibernate, postgresql, quartz-scheduler, multi-tenant

I'm currently implementing a multi tenant web application, with some background tasks run either by timers or by Quartz jobs.

For this I'm using [Hibernate 4 multitenant features](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html#d5e4684) and using a schema based strategy. The schema switching is made by invoking the following in my implementation of MultiTenantConnectionProvider:

```
connection.createStatement().execute("SET search_path TO '" + tenantIdentifier + "'");
```

The issue rises only in Quartz Job executions, the same code under a TimerTask works without any problem. For a number of good reasons I want to use Quartz over Timer (persistence, error handling, triggering facilities).

When a job the iterates over the list of tenants and runs, in a new transaction, a query, the query sometimes returns the correct value for each tenant, sometimes returns the value for another tenant.

I have enable TRACE log level in Hibernate and Spring and I can see the sessions being opened for each tenant.

I have also track the statements executed in the database log and clearly something is going wrong. This is an ok execution:

```
SET search_path TO public

SET search_path TO 'tenantA'
BEGIN
/* criteria query */
select * from TABLE1_ this_ where this_.published_=
 = 't'
/* load one-to-many */
select * from TABLE2_ where id_table1_=
 = '1234'
COMMIT

SET search_path TO public

SET search_path TO 'tenantB'
BEGIN
/* criteria query */
select * from TABLE1_ this_ where this_.published_=
 = 't'
/* load one-to-many */
select * from TABLE2_ where id_table1_=
 = '5678'
/* load collection */
select * from TABLE3_  where id_table2_=
 = '9876'
COMMIT

SET search_path TO public
```

And this the same execution when the issue manifests:

```
SET search_path TO public

SET search_path TO 'tenantA'
BEGIN
/* criteria query */
select * from TABLE1_ this_ where this_.published_=
 = 't'
/* load one-to-many */
select * from TABLE2_ where id_table1_=
 = '5678'
/* load collection */
select * from TABLE3_  where id_table2_=
 = '9876'
COMMIT

SET search_path TO public

SET search_path TO 'tenantB'
BEGIN
/* criteria query */
    select * from TABLE1_ this_ where this_.published_=
 = 't'
/* load one-to-many */
select * from TABLE2_ where id_table1_=
 = '1234'
COMMIT

SET search_path TO public
```

In this case, the queries are swapped, in others executes the same for the two tenants. When analysing the database logs it seems that the sessionid is the same for the same queries.

Triple checking my self, I print the result of `SHOW search_path;` inside the transaction and it returned the correct path, always.

Again, this behaviour is not present when the code runs inside a TimerTask.

Any ideas? I realize that this is a complex problem hard to understand if you haven't experienced yourself. But that is what I'm hoping, that someone has already pass through the same and can shed some light on the matter.
If needed I can provide further info but for now I think is enough to illustrate the issue.

Environment:

- Java 7
- Spring 3.2.6
- Hibernate 4.2.12
- Quartz 2.2.1
- PostgreSQL 9.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok solution found. Not a Hibernate Multi Tenancy problem. I try implementing my own Data Source proxying mechanism and the issue remained. No Quartz problem either, even the issue I report earlier that was happening in this context, was one of many. After completely disabling Quartz other issues rise in the same erratic and random way.

> **The Solution:** Use PostgresSQL 9.3.

Why? No Idea. Lost some minutes reading the changelogs, but after days struggling with this I have much to catch up. If someone has a clue, please share.